# Adding multiple Geofence to a map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-geofence

So far I'm able to add single geofence to the map with help of this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639). Actually I'm adding markers to the map on map click event allowing me to add multiple markers on touch. I wan't to add geofence to all the markers that I'm adding. I've tried making few changes in particular methods of the above tutorial as

```
ArrayList<LatLng> locs= new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    // Create a marker for the geofence creation
private void markerForGeofence(LatLng latLng) {
    Log.i(TAG, "markerForGeofence(" + latLng + ")");
    String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
    // Define marker options
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
            .title(title);
    if (map != null) {
        // Remove last geoFenceMarker
      //  if (geoFenceMarker != null)
      //      geoFenceMarker.remove();

        geoFenceMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);  
        gfmarkr.add(geoFenceMarker);
    }
}
...
   // Start Geofence creation process
private void startGeofence() {
    Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
    if (geoFenceMarker != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gfmarkr.size(); i++) {
            Geofence geofence = createGeofence(locs.get(i), GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
            GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
            addGeofence(geofenceRequest);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Geofence marker is null");
    }
}
```

**In short what is the method of adding more than one geofence.** Any solution will be of great help. Thankyou.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Adding geofence and knowing when user enters or exits or you want to show Geofence in map?

Comment: @NinjaCoder Adding more than one geofence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved. I passed `locs.get(i)` to all the methods that are responsible for creating a particular Geofence and used it as a point of reference for position. Also, I removed the statements

```
 if (geoFenceLimits != null)
    geoFenceLimits.remove();
```

from `drawGeofence()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a location update, if the ArrayList of all your geofences is more than 100, remove all geofences been monitored and then calculate the 100 nearest geofences using the harvesine formula:

```
public static final double R = 6372.8; // In kilometers

public static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
  double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
  double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
  lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
  lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

  double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
  double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
  return R * c;
}
```

That will give you the distance between the two locations. After that you could compare that distance with the geofence region radius to know if is inside the region.
Note: This distance will be in kilometers if your radius is on meters then just multiply the haversine method result with 1000 so that it's converted to meters.

[Reference](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: Okay but I don't know the method for adding more than one geofence. What can I do for that?

Comment: sorry, but I am with such not encountered. sorry, but I can't help

Comment: But you gave solution to add more than 100 geofences. How do you add those 100 fences?